# How to name my custom HTTP codes?

Tags: http, http-headers, standards, httpresponse

We're building a backend with a number of APIs. What should be the ideal range of HTTP codes that I should be using?

I've gone through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and they give a list such as:

```
1xx Informational
2xx Success
3xx Redirection
4xx Client Error
5xx Server Error
```

But since I want to implement my own status codes for various purposes such as `missing email`, I want to name the response accordingly.

So, according to me, a missing email response should trigger a 4xx response as it's a client error. What I'm trying to understand is that should I look for the first open slot such as #419 or should I begin to number the HTTP codes after #451?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use any custom codes at all - they might conflict with future standardization.

If you think you have a use case for a new code that is of general use, propose it in the right place (the HTTP Working Group).

If you just need something specific to your application, use a 400 (in this case), and provide additional information in the response body.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easy to spot issues within my application if I used them?